# HtmlAgilityPack giving exception "Multiple node elments can't be created."

Tags: html-agility-pack

I have some input tags that are placeholders that I am replacing with some HTML. I am using below code to create html node below is the code snippet. But it is giving error as "Multiple node elements can't be created" when there are no multiple nodes.

```
string tempString = "<p style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;text-indent:0px;text-align:justify;">(c)<span style='display: inline-block; width: 30px; min-width: 30px;'>&nbsp;</span><span class='noCount4'> </span>paragraph <span class="Ellh_">(a)<span class='noCount-44'> </span>&nbsp;of Clause <span class='noCount-48'> </span><span class="Ellj_">25.3<span class='noCount-44'> </span>&nbsp;(<span class='noCount-49'></span> </span><i>Other obligations</i>) as a result of an <span class="El2d_">Obligor </span>failing to comply with its obligations under Clause <span class="Ellm_">24.22<span class='noCount-44'> </span>&nbsp;(<span class='noCount-50'></span> </span><i><span class="El2e_">Financial Indebtedness</i></span>);<span class='noCount-1'> </span></span></p>"

HtmlNode tempNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode(tempString);
```

But `HtmlNode.CreateNode(tempString)` is giving error "Multiple node elements can't be created".

can any one suggest me what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 13):

"Multiple node elements can't be created" is correct however this is can be miss-leading. HtmlNode.CreateNode() only supports single node HTML, that is can only have one external container node.

Change this...

```
<p>
    blah blah...
</p> 
<span>
    More stuff... 
</span>
```

Into this...

```
<div>
   <p>
      blah blah...
   </p>
   <span>
      More stuff...
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Before I find this answer, I was thinking of splitting all the tags into HtmlNode.CreateNodes to avoid this error! Luckily I googled.