# HTMLAgilityPack error: "Multiple node elements can't be created."

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm attempting to use the HTMLAgilityPack to get retrieve and edit inner text of some HTML. The inner text of each node i retrieve needs to be checked for matching strings and those matching strings to be highlighted like so:

```
var HtmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
HtmlDoc.LoadHtml(item.Content);

var nodes = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='guide_subtitle_cell']/p");
foreach (HtmlNode htmlNode in nodes)
{
    htmlNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlTextNode.CreateNode(Methods.HighlightWords(htmlNode.InnerText, searchstring)), htmlNode);
}
```

This is the code for the HighlightWords method I use:

```
public static string HighlightWords(string input, string searchstring)
    {
        if (input == null || searchstring == null)
        {
            return input;
        }

        var lowerstring = searchstring.ToLower();
        var words = lowerstring.Split(' ').ToList();

        for (var i = 0; i < words.Count; i++)
        {
            Match m = Regex.Match(input, words[i], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (m.Success)
            {
                string ReplaceWord = string.Format("<span class='search_highlight'>{0}</span>", m.Value);
                input = Regex.Replace(input, words[i], ReplaceWord, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            }
        }

        return input;
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to get this working or indicate what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `HtmlTextNode.CreateNode` can only create one node. When you add a `<span>` inside, that's another node, and `CreateNode` throws the exception you see.

Make sure that you are only doing a search and replace on the lowest leaf nodes (nodes with no children). Then rebuild that node by:

1. Create a new empty node to replace the old one
2. Search for the text in `.InnerText`
3. Use `HtmlTextNode.Create` to add the plain text *before* the text you want to highlight
4. Then add your new `<span>` with the highlighted text with `HtmlNode.CreateNode`
5. Then search for the next occurrence (start back at 1) until no more occurrences are found.

Answer (score 0):

Your function HighlightWords must be returning multiple top-level HTML nodes. For example:

```
<p>foo</p>
<span>bar</span>
```

The HtmlAgilityPack only allows one top-level node to be returned. You can hardcode the return value for HighlightWords to test.

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48428938/htmlagilitypack-giving-exception-multiple-node-elments-cant-be-created) has run across the same problem.